# compute a length excluding periodic segments

Tags: date-and-time

I have a range `[start, end]` and I need to compute its length excluding a periodic range defined by `[offset, length, period]`

eg.

```
offset: 2
length: 3
period: 7


--XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----XXX----...
    ===================================
    start                           end

start: 4
end: 38

result is 14
```

It is quite easy to find the result by iterating, but I need to find an expression of the result, without loops or conditions

The first step is easy:

```
(end - start) - floor((end - start)/period) * length
```

But the overlapping is more tricky to handle

**EDIT**
the underlying problem I try to solve is the following:

1/ I have a `orderDate` (in ms starting at epoch) and a `deliveryDuration` (in ms)
2/ I have some recurrent off periods (eg. from 6pm to 8am, from friday 6pm to monday 8am, ...)
-> then I need to compute the deliveryDate like this: startDate + deliveryDuration + all-off-periods-that-intersects (the reason is that my carrier does not work during nights and week-ends)
**example**:
 `orderDate`: friday 5pm
 `deliveryDuration`: 2h
 then `deliveryDate` will be monday 9am)

Comment: I could definitely use an example.

Comment: I tried hard but did not understand (what is the offset, does the periodic sequence has a specific beginning, etc.).

Comment: Is this a mathematics (then wrong forum) or a Wolfram Language (Mathematica) question (the it lacks code attempts)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to reproduce your sequence. For convenience, I replaced the elements you don't want to count ("X") with $0$, and the ones you want counted with $1$:

```
ClearAll[sequence]
sequence[{offset_, length_, period_}, {start_, finish_}] /; length < period :=
 Join[
   ConstantArray[1, offset],
   Piecewise[{
     {0, With[{mod = Mod[#, period]}, Or @@ Distribute[mod == Range[length], List]]},
     {1, True}}
   ] & /@ Range[start + 1, finish + 1]
 ]
```

For instance, to generate the first 20 elements in a sequence with your offset of 2, with an ignored-character sequence length of 3, and period of 7:

```
sequence[{2, 3, 7}, {0, 20}]

(* Out: {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

With this, counting the non-"X" slots in the above sequence is equivalent to taking the sum of the sequence (e.g. with `Total`). For instance, between positions 4 and 12:

```
sequence[{2, 3, 7}, {4, 12}]
Total@%

(* Out:
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
8
*)
```

and indeed, that corresponds to the eight non-"X" slots.

---

Notice also that the example you proposed does not seem to work; no matter how I try to interpret your labels, I can't reconcile your result with the scheme in the OP.